# Is there a way to make clang aware of custom opaque type reference counting?

Tags: c, clang, reference-counting, opaque-pointers

I have some opaque types and have implemented a reference counting semantic that mimics Core Foundation. This works well enough except that clang warns me of semi valid potential leaks.

```
MyTypeRef MyTypeRefCreateWithSomething(…) {
    MyTypeRef value = MyTypeRefCreate(…);
    MyTypeRef adjustedValue = MyTypeRefCreate(…);
    MyTypeRefRelease(value);
    return adjustedValue; // clang says that this might be a leak of `value`… 
     // which is only true if something goes wrong with reference counting.
 }
```

I am looking for something like [`attribute_cf_consumed`](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_cf_consumed) or a simple way to make my own version.

For reference, this is how I currently silence the warning. It works but it is, in my opinion, as bad as just leaving the warnings in. (I ifdef the `if` statement that surrounds `MytypeRelease`'s call to `free`)

```
void MyTypeRelease(MyTypeRef degree) {
    ((MyMutableTypeRef)degree)->refCount--;
    #ifndef __clang_analyzer__
    if ((degree->refCount <= 0) && !MyTypeIsNull(degree)) {
    #endif /*__clang_analyzer__*/
        free((CTJUMTMutableScaleDegree)degree);
    #ifndef __clang_analyzer__
    }
    #endif /*__clang_analyzer__*/
}
```

Comment: You have **two** values created following 'Create' rules, and you release only **one** `value`, `adjustedValue` is never released. In your sample the warning seems correct to me.

Comment: @Emmanuel This is a 'Create' function, besides which, it is still not a leak. I am returning a reference to the value that I did not release.

Comment: Your modification changes everything concerning my previous comment, which is no more valid.